# Parse XML with jquery ajax and xpath

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, xpath

I stuck with following constellation:

[JSBIN Example](http://jsbin.com/apijo4/11/edit)

I want a click function for Check Availibility that does a jquery ajax with a given url (i.e. http://kiris-alinda.de/temp/verify.php) checks if the attribute @ges has a value (ie ges="1234") or not (ie ges="") and finally alerts "true" or "false"

XML Response with true: http://kiris-alinda.de/temp/verify_true.php
XML Response with false: http://kiris-alinda.de/temp/verify_false.php

Thanks a lot in advance for your feedback and an interesting discussion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this approach

```js
$.ajax({     
    url: 'http://kiris-alinda.de/temp/verify.php',    
    type: 'GET',    
    datatype: 'xml',    
    success: function(responseValue) {  
        var gesVal = $(responseValue).find('ges').text();

        if(gesVal !=null && gesVal !=undefined && gesVal != ""){
              alert("true");
        }else{
              alert("false");
        }

    },     
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {         
         //error handling goes here     
    } 
});
```

Comment: may be its too much and I apologize for this but I need help in doing the ajax request, parsing the attribute and so on... thx for your feedback so long

Comment: not yet. tried some $.ajax and hoped from help of stackoverflow;) I need more practice with this

Comment: The ajax request produces an error. So I can't do the success function

Comment: I have knocked up a quick test html page and it works for me with no problems? With more error/debug info I am sure we can help you further

Comment: //ajax:start 
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://kiris-alinda.de/temp/verify.php',
      type: 'GET',    
      datatype: 'xml', 
      success: function(xml) {
        
           $(xml).find("search").each(function(){
            $(".result").append($(this).attr("ges") + "<br />");
            });
  
        
        //$('.result').html(data);
        //alert('Load was performed.');
      }
    });
    //ajax:end

Answer (score 0):

To perform the AJAX call the jQuery is as follows

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://kiris-alinda.de/temp/verify.php',
    type: 'GET',
    datatype: 'xml',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //xml returned in 'data' - interrogate for response here
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //error handling goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: how can you do xpath like queries on that?